# No matching distribution found for selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pip

I’ve been trying to run: `python setup.py` command but the following error keeps occurring:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement selenium (from versions : )
No matching distribution found for selenium
```

I'm running Linux with python 2.7.14+

How can I solve this?

Comment: Might be worth checking: if you are using pip, try to run `pip install --upgrade pip` before running again and see if https://bhch.github.io/posts/2017/04/fix-the-pip-error-couldnt-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requirement/ applies to your case (it's hard for me to tell what would work without more details).

Comment: Thank you! Still got the same error even after upgrading pip though. Tried “Pip install selenium” and also got the same “no matching distribution found for selenium”. I’m trying to run a script from git hub: I first cloned it, using “get clone”, then chmod the files using “chmod +x faitagram && chmod +x setup.py” and then used “python setup.py” to install the requirements. That’s when the errror occurred.

Comment: Might be helpful to flag on their github repo the issue you are experiencing with Faitagram. Also, be careful about how you use it ;) If you specify the package you are trying to install by editing your question you might also get better help on SO.